# Issue with Decimal Rounding in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, rounding

All,

I have a set `decimal` values in C#. I am writing these to fields in a class then serialising this class to an XML data file. However, I have an issue when trying to round a value that is stored as zero or 0, to four decimal places. I want 0 to be stored as 0.0000. Is this possible using `decimal`? Of course I can do this without issue when casting to `string`, and this is not the problem. I have read many threads but none seem to address this issue.

Any help would be most appreciated. The code snippit I have is:

```
// directCost (dCost).
decimal dCost = Convert.ToDecimal(EpiCostValues[(int)epiCostField.directCost]);
dCost = decimal.Round(dCost, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
episodeCostTmp.dCost = dCost;

// indirectCost (iCost).
decimal iCost = Convert.ToDecimal(EpiCostValues[(int)epiCostField.indirectCost]);
iCost = decimal.Round(iCost, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
episodeCostTmp.iCost = iCost;
```

But this does not force 0 to 0.0000, which is a problem for the required format of the .xml data file.

Comment: What's creating the XML file? It sounds like that's where you should be handling the formatting...

Comment: how are you getting it to xml?

Comment: The binary value ( i.e. int value ) of 0 is 00000000 the value for 0.0 as a decimal value is the same ( just more zeros ) in other words your problem deals with the format as a string ( i.e. the binary value of this will NOT be zero ) do some more research on the subject.

Comment: I create the XML file according to a class hierarchy created using the xsd.exe tool. I then build the class structure using the auto-generated classes and then serialise this class using `XmlWriter writer;` and `serializer.Serialize(writer, myclass);'. I could force the class to store this value as a string instead of a decimal, but this would violate the schema we have been provided.

Comment: @RamHound. The decimal type doesn't normalize itself - it remembers how many decimal digits it has (by maintaining the exponent where possible) and on formatting, zero may be counted as a significant decimal digit. I light of this, no, it is not treating the decimal as a string. In fact, .NET uses a scaling factor which preserves any trailing zeroes in a Decimal number. Trailing zeroes do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. This formatting is revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this line into your code

```
dCost *= 1.0000m;
```

For Eg:

```
// directCost (dCost).
decimal dCost = Convert.ToDecimal(EpiCostValues[(int)epiCostField.directCost]);
dCost *= 1.0000m;
dCost = decimal.Round(dCost, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
episodeCostTmp.dCost = dCost;
```

Hope this Helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is to do with formatting the value as a string, not how it is stored.  The value is stored in binary, it's the part where you change it to a string that has the problem.  You could try : `string.Format("{0:0.0000}", iCost);`

Comment: No. I have stated clearly in the question this is NOT the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you judging whether or not it's stored with 4d.p., if not by converting to string?  Decimal stores with way more than 4d.p. by default (well, s.f. not d.p.).  Therefore you are very likely confused by converting to a string (e.g. to view in a debugger) with the wrong format string.

Comment: By the way, if you're so sure of something, and someone points out that you may be mistaken, that's a weird attitude to take, considering you're the one asking the question, and the other person is offering you help, for free.  You should at least reconsider that you might be mistaken.  If everything you are thinking is correct, then you wouldn't have a problem.  Therefore something you are thinking is not.

Comment: Thanks. I meant no disrespect by this what-so-ever, and should not have been so terse in my reply. I am in a position when I have to serialise this data according to the provided schema, which I cannot edit. This takes `decimals` only for the above fields. This decimal fields is being serialised to XML and it is here where I can see the error. Of course you are right in regards to the fact that I will have to at some point revile the underlying formatting by changing to String, but I know from the writing process that the `decimal` itself is not being stored with four decimal places.

Comment: Can you reveal how you determine that it is not being stored with 4 d.p. please?  Your example based on 0 is not a good one, since 0.0000 is obviously = 0.

Comment: Formatting of any decimal number is stored within the number itself. This formatting is exposed by the ToString method or some other "equivelent" conversion, like serialising the data to XML. In my XML file the string for all "iCost"s or "dCost" that are zero is 0. Whereas, for all other fields the correct rounding is taking place. The data for the cost componants are coming from SQL Server and are passed as 0, not 0.000000000. This is how I came to this conclusion. By multiplying the cost by `1.0000m', and then doing the rounding I have solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time and aplogies for my first comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the additional precision until you format the output of your number. E.g. nothing will say the number is 1.0000 rather than simply 1 or 1.0. However when the number is 1.2345 - you will see that level of precision.

So what you've done is fine. Format it to 4 decimal places when you write it to your file, and you will get .0000 when it's a whole number, or .2345 (or whatever it is) when the precision is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think when serializing the values of all fields are converted to string with the ToString() method. maybe you could override this method in a new type which inherits from decimal or write an extension method (don't know if it works though).